# ckeditor removing form tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im using ckeditor 4.13.1 and when pasting html into the source dialog box and clicking ok the form tags and markup are being removed. Everything inside those tags remains. The config currently includes `config.allowedContent = true;` and `config.pasteFilter = true;`.

```
<form id="contact-form" class="row">
    <textarea id="page-editor"></textarea>
    <button class="btn btn-default pull-right" type="button"><i class="fas fa-paper-plane fa-fw"></i> Send</button>
</form>
```

This is the config

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function(config) {
    config.allowedContent = true;
    config.pasteFilter = null;
    config.startupFocus = true;
    config.floatSpacePreferRight = true;
};
CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty['i'] = false;
```

This is how I initialize

```
CKEDITOR.inline('page-editor', {
    customConfig: '/javascript/ckeditor/editableConfig.js'
}).on('blur', function(e) {
    return false;
});
```

Strangely if I add another form tag before my current form tag only the first is removed and the second remains.

Example

```
<form></form>
<form id="contact-form" class="row">
    <textarea id="page-editor"></textarea>
    <button class="btn btn-default pull-right" type="button"><i class="fas fa-paper-plane fa-fw"></i> Send</button>
</form>
```

Why is ckeditor removing the form tags and how can I stop it?